# Javascript - setTimeout function

Tags: javascript

i try to develop a page and i have to use setTimeout function because i need to load my video in my page two seconds later.

In order to do that, i wrote this,

```
 window.onload = function () {
        player = new Player('playerObject');
        setTimeout(player.playByUrl($mp4Link),3000);
    }
```

but this is not working why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 3):

Use callback:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   player.playByUrl($mp4Link);
},3000);
```

With your previous statement, the code was executing ***immediately*** (because you were calling it directly by specifying param and parenthesis eg `playByUrl($mp4Link)`) whereas `setTimeout` needs a callback.

Comment: It would be more helpful to say *why* and explain what the OP's original code is actually doing.

Comment: @user1277467: Yes you are right.

Comment: Player.prototype.playByUrl = function (url) {
        this.object.data = url;
        return this.play();
    } this is my function that i call and this is not work  window.onload = function () {
        player = new Player('playerObject');
        setTimeout(player.playByUrl.bind(null,$mp4Link),3000);
    } why

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add parameters to the function. However you can simply use an anonymuos function as callback and call the function in there (with the parameters).

```
window.onload = function () {
    player = new Player('playerObject');
    setTimeout(function() {
        player.playByUrl($mp4Link);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout requires a function

```
window.onload = function () {
   player = new Player('playerObject');
   setTimeout(function(){
       player.playByUrl($mp4Link);
   },3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `function` reference to `setTimeout`, but I guess the return value from `.playByUrl()` is not a function. So either go with

```
setTimeout(function() {
    player.playByUrl($mp4Link);
},3000);
```

or use ES5 `.bind()`

```
setTimeout(player.playByUrl.bind(null,$mp4Link),3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`player.playByUrl($mp4Link)` is the returned value.

try

`setTimeout("player.playByUrl($mp4Link)",3000);`

or

`setTimeout(player.playByUrl,3000, $mp4Link);`

The latter does not work with IE and so should be modified.

Comment: window.onload = function () {
        player = new Player('playerObject');
        setTimeout(player.playByUrl($mp4Link),10000);
    } this is not working why :(

Comment: I have explained above. `player.playByUrl($mp4Link)` is some value other than a function.

Answer (score -1):

try to add `player.load();` as follow:

```
  player.load();
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    player.setAttribute("src","http://www.w3school.com.cn/example/html5/mov_bbb.mp4");
    player.play();
  },5000)
```